# Django joined path for uploaded files

Tags: django

(There are 5 or 6 different SO questions and answers that deal with similar problems – I've tried implementing their solutions without success.)

I'm trying to implement a page where a user can drag-and-drop to upload an Excel file that will then subsequently be parsed and information extracted to create various models.

The files upload without any problems and are successfully stored on the server and are referenced in a FileField in a model.

However, I cannot get my subsequent function, using xlrd, to access the file. Any attempt to reference the file results in a 400 Bad Request, with the error that the joined path is located outside the base path component.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have also tried the same as above, as suggested in other posts, with a trailing slash for the _ROOTs.

The resulting errors (for example, calling the file via File.file.path) are always of the form:

```
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/media/sheet.xlsx) is located outside of the base path 
component (/PATH-TO-DJANGO-APP/SchedulePosting/media)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting file with full path. Provide django `BASE_DIR` before file path. like this:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, File.file.path.lstrip('/'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produces the same result for me (this was also suggested in some of the other SO posts on the same topic). But it led me to a temporary solution - the problem seems to be with os.path.join() - manually concatenating settings.BASE_DIR and the file.path produces the correct result. Using os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,File.file.path) always returns only the file.path, without BASE_DIR.

Comment: updated it. It's because `os.path.join` doesn't concat strings if there is `/` in first character of each string. the previous strings will be ignored.